# Multiple test libraries in TFS 2015 build definition

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

How do you specify multiple test DLLs in a TFS 2015 build definition? There is a wildcard definition *test*.dll that doesn't work for me as some of the test projects are not supposed to run in the build. I tried separating the DLL names by semicolon but it seems that only the first test DLL is run and the rest is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these test projects to the project list in the build definition.
Go to build definition, Process -> Projects. Like:

[image]

Then you will be able to run tests included in the test projects.

Comment: That doesn't work for the new (non-XAML) build definitions any longer.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard notation supports exclusions by prefixing them with "-:". 
You could do something like this:

```
**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll;-:**\butnotme.dll;-:**\orme.dll
```

Or, if you want to specify only the dlls that should be included (note that path expressions beyond the first might need an absolute directory placeholder such as `$(build.sourcesDirectory)` to work:

```
**\$(BuildConfiguration)\firsttest.dll;$(build.sourcesDirectory)\**\$(BuildConfiguration)\secondtest.dll
```

See [this blog post](https://blogs.infosupport.com/tfs2015-build-tasks-the-wildcard-format-explained/) for the exact details of what is allowed in a wildcard expression.